# While connecting to azure cosmos Db from docker it is throwing error i.e No Such host known

Tags: visual-studio, docker, azure-cosmosdb

While connecting to azure cosmos Db from docker it is throwing error in Visual Studio i.e **No Such host known**.

Azure cosmos is publicly accessible and I am able to access with Simple Web Api in Visual Studio. But It is not accessible **through docker app at local system.**
version: '3.4'

services:

nyrr.xcapi.cartservice:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}nyrrxcapicartservice
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Services\Cart\Nyrr.XCApi.Cart\Dockerfile
ports:
- "5104:80"

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with the Docker file?

Comment: Docker compose file text added

Answer (score 0):

There are some docs on running the Cosmos emulator on Docker [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-docker) that may be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I want to connect with Azure cosmos db not azure cosmos emulator.

Comment: Actually, Docker app is not connecting with any external service such as azure redis, azure cosmos etc